# AWS Amplify: A flag to disable overrides has been detected, please deploy from a different environment. at buildOverrideDir

Tags: reactjs, aws-amplify

Earlier in AWS amplify console, i was able to successfully able to modify data model, save and deploy.

From today modifying any data model, I click "Save & Deploy", getting this error in console:

A flag to disable overrides has been detected, please deploy from a different environment. at buildOverrideDir

Infra details:

- Using React JS as front end

Please let me know of any questions or information?

I reverted my last 5 code-commit but still the issue. Where is this buildOverrideDir, I can't find.

Comment: Have you had any news on this?

Comment: No not yet. I opened TT with AWS support. They are still researching.

Comment: Let me know if you get any news on this! My team is also stuck with it.  Have you tried using Amplify Studio?

Comment: Had a similar issue with Amplify Studio. But was able to update data model making necessary edits in schema.graphql and pushing changes from my machine to the cloud: `amplify push api`

Comment: Thanks for the heads up @Edgar! we're taking the same approach but did this solve your issue with buildOverrideDir flag?

Comment: Yes, pushing changes from my machine worked fine. Whereas Amplify Studio had issues.

Comment: Thats true, `amplify push api` does update the schema in backend. But it's not updating the inbuilt amplify forms for me. And as a result, i am blocked using the dat model and inbuilt forms. Still waiting on AWS support. They are working with internal core team.

Answer (score 1):

I've found this:
https://docs.amplify.aws/console/adminui/extend-cli/#authentication-tokens

 wich was causing some conflict errors inside the amplify project.
So the solution in my case was to delete the override.ts file.
Let me know if you actually solved with this